# $status in Fish prompt always prints 0

Tags: prompt, fish

I tried to add `$status` to my prompt in the fish shell but it always prints 0.

This question was asked on irc a while back and i'm surprised there wasn't a answer here so i thought i'd post it here as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is because any function / command you call from within your prompt will reset the value. To make it work assign the value to another variable as the first thing you do in your fish_prompt or fish_right_prompt function.

```
function fish_prompt  --description 'Write out the prompt'
     set -l _display_status $status

     ...

     printf '%s' $_display_status
end
```